# AWK - SED - add a character to the beginning of every column if it starts with a number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How can I add a character to the beginning of every column that starts with a number:

Example adding a `c` to:
`4 r4 8 8 4`

So I get this output:
`c4 r4 c8 c8 c4`

It should work for a variable number of columns.

Comment: `sed 's/\<[0-9]/c&/g'` would also work for the given sample input...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an `awk`-oneliner like this:

- `echo '4 r4 8 8 4' | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0-9]/) $i = "c" $i }1'`

---

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to modify every column at once :

```
sed -E 's/(^| )([[:digit:]])/\1c\2/g' input
```

If your field separator is anything else than a space replace the space `(^| )` in this part of the regular expression with your field separator.

- `-E` specify to use Extended Regular Expression (ERE) instead of Basic Regular expression (BRE)
- `s` : `s/regexp/replacement/`
- `(^| )` match the beginning of a line or a space in a capture group
- `([[:digit:]])` match a digit in a capture group
- `\1c\2` the content of the first capture group (`\1`), the character `c`, the content of the second capture group (`\2`)
- `g` globally

Once the result satisfies you and if your `sed` implementation supports it, you may add `-i` (`-i ''` on FreeBSD or derivatives such as macos) to modify the file in-place. (`-i.bak` if you want to make a backup of your original file)

Comment: Shorter form: `s/\b([0-9])/c\1/g`. But not exactly equivalent if columns can begin with a non-alphanumeric symbol

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g / <(^ | \s+)> \d  /{$/}c/;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g /  (^ | \s+) (\d) /$0c$1/;'  file
```

Here are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Above, the file is read with the `-pe` linewise autoprinting flags. The substitution will be `:g` global and says:  "*If the start-of-line `^` or `\s+` whitespace is encountered followed by a `\d` digit, substitute."*

In the first example the match after whitespace is dropped using Raku's `<(…)>` capture markers. The resultant `$/` match-object is output in the replacement, followed by the letter `c`. In the second example, the entire match is contained in two captures (`$0` and `$1`), and output in the replacement as `$0c$1`.

Sample Input:

```
4 r4 8 8 4
```

Sample Output:

```
c4 r4 c8 c8 c4
```

Alternatively (and much more explicitly), below will "regularize" whitespace between columns:

```
~$ raku -ne 'put .split(/ \s+ /).map: *.subst(/^ \d /, {"c$/" // ""});'  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'put .split(/ \s+ /).map: *.subst(/^ (\d) /, {"c$0" // ""});'   file
```

First the input line is `.split` on variable whitespace (`\s+`), then each column is `map`ped into in order to `subst`itute any columns `^` starting with a `\d`, adding a `c` before the match (here using `$/` match-object or `$0`). If the match is undefined (using Raku's `//` "defined-OR" operator), insert `""` nothing. Columns are returned with a single whitespace between them.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a regular expression to test if each field starts with a number:

```bash
echo '4 r4 8 8 4' | awk '
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+/) 
      printf "c%s%s", $i, i == NF ? ORS : OFS
    else
      printf "%s%s", $i, i == NF ? ORS : OFS
}'
```

output:

```
c4 r4 c8 c8 c4
```

Comment: May be shortened to `for ... printf "%s%s", ($i ~ /^[0-9]+/ ? "c" : "")$i, i == NF ? ORS : OFS`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk`:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(^|\s+)([0-9]+)/,"\\1c\\2", "g")}1' 

# The command for numbers instead of digits only
$ awk -v var="c" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ $i = ($i==$i+0 ? var : "") $i}}1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    echo "4 r4 8 8 4" | sed -E 's/\<([[:digit:]])/c\1/g'
```

Comment: Note that in that case the *columns* are assumed to be separated by anything that is not a word character. So for instance on `a-2.3 4.5`, that would yield `a-c2.c3 c4.c5`. You could also simplify it to `sed 's/\<[[:digit:]]/c&/g'`. Also beware the `\<` is not standard, -E will soon be standard. Some alternatives to `\<` (not standard either) you may find with other `sed` implementations are `\b` (from perl) or `[[:<:]]` on some BSDs IIRC

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (`mlr`) to apply a function that prepends the character `c` to a field's value, if it is a number:

```bash
$ mlr --nidx put '$* = apply($*, func(k,v) { ch = (is_numeric(v) ? "c" : ""); return { k: ch . v } })' file
c4 r4 c8 c8 c4
```

This uses Miller to read the data as a Unix toolbox-formatted data set (newline-delimited records with space-delimited fields) and applies a `put` expression to each record.

The `put` expression uses `apply()` to apply an anonymous function to each field.  The function tests the field's value, and if it is numeric, it prepends the value with `c`, otherwise it leaves it unmodified.

The `is_numeric()` test is *true* for **numbers**, not just digits.  This is what the question specifically asks for:

```bash
$ cat file
4 r4 8.8 8e7 -4 9hello
$ mlr --nidx put '$* = apply($*, func(k,v) { ch = (is_numeric(v) ? "c" : ""); return { k: ch . v } })' file
c4 r4 c8.8 c8e7 c-4 9hello
```

Would you want to test for an initial **digit**, simply replace the `is_numeric()` test with a test for an initial digit:

```bash
$ cat file
4 r4 8.8 8e7 -4 9hello
$ mlr --nidx put '$* = apply($*, func(k,v) { ch = (v =~ "^[[:digit:]]" ? "c" : ""); return { k: ch . v } })' file
c4 r4 c8.8 c8e7 -4 c9hello
```